# How can I have together the lines in a flot chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I have this function:

```
 flotLinea:function(tareas){

var self = this;


var options = {

        legend: {

                position:"nw",

                },

        lines: 
                {
                    show: true,
                    fill: true
                },
        points: 
                { 
                    show: true
                },
        xaxis: 
                {
                    mode: "time",
                    minTickSize: [0, "day"],
                    timeformat: "%d/%m/%y"
                },
        yaxis: 
                {
                    min: 0,
                    tickSize:10,
                    tickDecimals: 0,
                },  

    };
    console.info(tareas);
    $.plot("#grafico",tareas,options);
},
```

The function print:

[image]

How can I have the lines together? or more close..

I need something like this :

[image]

I don't want so much space between the lines

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the function, only the settings passed.

The problem is the two data-sets are used on the same chart and your x-axis data has a gap. You need to shift your blue line array x-axis data left by one month.

So without seeing your code, let's suppose you have the following pseudo-code for your blue line:

```
[[19-8-15, 40],[20-8-15, 50],[21-8-15, 50],etc...]
```

The first element needs to be shifted left:

```
[[18-8-15, 40],[19-8-15, 50],[20-8-15, 50],etc...] //<==== months now one less
```

To achieve this, you need to use timestamps and then subtract the amount of seconds in a month and apply it iteratively to your blue series.

Post you function that creates the data and we'll go from there...